# How to make Silverlight DataGrid wide enough to show entire RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am creating the DataGrid and RowDetailsTemplate in code, so I don't have XAML to share. Sorry about that.

As you can see the RowDetailsTemplate is truncated. Any idea how to make the grid wide enough to show the whole thing?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the DataGrid's parent does not have HorizontalAlignment set to "Stretch".